# a confirmation after C-x C-c before exiting Emacs

Tags: key-bindings, exit

Can I configure Emacs to ask for confirmation before exiting on `C-x C-c`? (Sometimes, my fingers press this by mistake.)

Comment: See also [Prevent Emacs from exiting once the exit procedure has initiated?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21192111/94687) for some other related suggestions.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Set the variable `confirm-kill-emacs` to something like `yes-or-no-p`.

Comment: Thanks! It's a pity it is not mentioned in `save-buffers-kill-terminal` documentation...

Comment: It's only mentioned for `save-buffers-kill-emacs`, which used to be the binding for `C-x C-c` until 23.1. That should be updated, it seems.

Comment: @imz--IvanZakharyaschev: Yes; likewise `kill-emacs-query-functions`. See Emacs [bug #10794](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=10794). (And [bug #11181](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=11181#22), though not directly related, is also relevant here.)

Answer (score 9):

I use this, which workds in all Emacs versions:

```
(add-hook 'kill-emacs-query-functions
          (lambda () (y-or-n-p "Do you really want to exit Emacs? "))
          'append)
```

Comment: It would be nice to explain how that is different from setting `confirm-kill-emacs`. IIUC, the difference is that `c-k-e` is ignored if there are modified buffers (which already asks confirmation) or active processes (also asks for confirmation).

Comment: @YoungFrog: What you say is true, but only for Emacs 25, not earlier. And `confirm-kill-emacs` does not exist prior to Emacs 21.

Answer (score 8):

A common alternative is to unbind the key using

```
(global-unset-key (kbd "C-x C-c"))
```

You can always quit via `M-x save-buffers-kill-terminal`